# “Writer” or “Author” when talking about somebody who “creates” book stories/novels as a professional?

Tags: word-choice

This question has been split from a previous double-question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/writer-or-author-when-talking-about-somebody-who-creates-book-stories-nove?noredirect=1).

---

Which of the following is preferable?

> Jack London and Charles Dickens were both great **writers**.
>
> Jack London and Charles Dickens were both great **authors**.

Could somebody explain that to me the difference?

Is there any difference in usage between British English and American English in this case?

Answer (score 2):

I think both can be used interchangeably. However in my view, authors write books while writer is a more generic term. The are other words for other media too, playwrights write plays, bloggers write blogs, reviews write reviews, poets write poems, but all are writers.

Comment: It's funny ;). Because the user Ramit write exactly the opposite to your statement  http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9547/what-is-the-difference-in-pronunciation-between-rider-and-writer (: `You are author of something. 'Author' is not an absolute word, it doesn't indicate profession. It demands object after it. 'Writer,' whereas, is a professional. It's an absolute word. You may not mention anything else along with it. Charles Dickens was a writer. He has authored many books. The word 'author' can be used for a non-writer as well. I am the author of my project assignment.`

Comment: @Derfder: I don't think _writer_ is any more "absolutely professional" than _author_. A _writer_ is someone who writes; it need not be a professional. I think either word can be used to indicate profession, and both words can also be used in other contexts as well.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks, but that's even more complicated now ;D It's Derek Knight VS Ramit VS J.R. ;D

Answer (score 2):

Most Americans today would say "I an a writer" not "I am an author." Writing organizations are called things like "The Science-Fiction Writers Association" not "The Science Fiction Authors Association." You can say either one, but "author" sounds old-fashioned. On the other hand, we say "author of" for a specific work and "writer of" for a genre. For example:

"Is Jack a writer?"

"Yes, he's the author of 'Death on Alpha Centauri.'"

"Is he a writer of science fiction?"

"Yes, and mysteries too."

Answer (score 1):

If someone dictated a book, they would be the Author, but not a "writer". There are also other phrases where "author" is not to do with writing, like "author of your own destiny". So, I think that authoring is more about creating, whereas writer is about... writing.

"Author" also implies a published work. Writer implies very little. I have been writing since I was able to, but nothing published yet.

Answer (score -1):

You are author of something. 'Author' is not an absolute word, it needn't indicate profession. It demands object after it. 'Writer,' whereas, is a professional. It's an absolute word. You may not mention anything else along with it.

Charles Dickens was a writer. He has authored many books.

The word 'author' can be used for a non-writer as well. I am the author of my project assignment.

Comment: *Author* can absolutely describe a profession; in fact, it's the very first meaning Macmillan gives: *[someone who writes books, articles etc, especially as their job](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/author)*. I could just as easily say *Charles Dickens was an author. He has written many books.*

Comment: @choster: True enough, but if we changed "doesn't" to "needn't," then I'd largely agree with most of this answer.